# Kivy: change TwoLineListItem text when press

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I have this code that reads the files I have in my storage, and It returns in TwoLineListItem.

Example: if I have 2 files will return 2 TwoLineListItem.

Code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.list import TwoLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.selection import *
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import os

KV = '''
ScreenManager:
    Screen:
        name: 'telaSelecionada'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            MDToolbar:
                id: tb
                title: ''
                md_bg_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            TelaSelecionada:
                id: telaselecionada
        
<TelaSelecionada>:  
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            id: mostraReceita


'''

class TelaSelecionada(FloatLayout):
    pass

class Aplicativo(MDApp):
    def on_start(self):
        self.listarReceitaBebida()
        
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
        
    def listarReceitaBebida(self):
        dir1 = '/storage/emulated/0/Receitas/BEBIDAS'
        os.chdir(dir1)
        self.root.ids.telaselecionada.ids.mostraReceita.clear_widgets()
        dic = {}
        i = 1
        for file in os.listdir():
            if file.endswith('.txt'):
                file_path = f"{dir1}/{file}"
                with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
                    lines = f.readlines()   
                    lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]
                    st_idx = lines.index("receita")
                    md_idx = lines.index("preparo")
                    ed_idx = lines.index("...")
                    l = lines[st_idx:ed_idx]
                    self.textLine = TwoLineListItem(text = str(l[1]), secondary_text = str(l[3]), on_press = self.abrirReceita)
            self.root.ids.telaselecionada.ids.mostraReceita.add_widget(self.textLine)
            self.root.ids.telaselecionada.ids.mostraReceita.ids[str(i)] = self.textLine
            i += 1
            self.dic = {self.textLine.text: file_path}      
            
    def abrirReceita(self,instance):
        self.textLine.text = str(instance)
        
Aplicativo().run()
```

What I'm trying to do is when I press the first button, the text of the first button change, when the second button is press, the  second button change.

My problem is when I click on any button, only the last one is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `self.textLine.text` (outside the for loop) refers to the last added item from the for loop. That's why only the last item's text is changing. What you need to do is access the instance and change its text.

Thus the change you might need,

```py
    def abrirReceita(self,instance):
        instance.text = str(instance)
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks man... That was so simple.